An object 'CompletionDisposition' of type StandardValueSet was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory
I'm a Salesforce admin trying to add custom values to the Sales Engagement product for when a prospect is removed from a cadence.  I am following these instructions:
https://org62.my.salesforce.com/sfc/p/#000000000062/a/3y000000UtcM/YciwGxf9haso.1WGdTG7X9m7I5N7qWmxqFE9hHJkJkg
I am receiving a deploy error in workbench "An object 'CompletionDisposition' of type StandardValueSet was named in package.xml, but was not found in zipped directory."
My package looks the same as linked instructions:

My value set xml looks the same as linked instructions, except I am attempting to add the custom values at the top instead, where it makes more sense for our use case (and since the instructions specifically say not to modify or delete standard values).

When I attempt to deploy, I am also selecting Single Package as I've seen some suggest, though I've also tried without.
Can someone please help me identify where the issue is?

An image or copy of the ZIP file would help us identify the exact problem. The problem is almost certainly caused by an invalid file structure within the ZIP file.
